# sql select statement, guide to correct select statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I should  write a SQL query that will select all of the books that are currently checked out and are past due to be returned, which have a value greater than $10.00 from a library system. I should return  the name, address, postal code, and phone number of the borrower, the name and phone number of the librarian responsible for the transaction, the date the book was due to be returned, and the name, cost, and ISBN number of the book. And  my query should be sorted  the list by the return date in descending order.

This is what i wrote

```
Select a.returndate as booklended ,a.isbn_number as booklended, b. as borrower,          
                    b.address as borrower, b.postalcode as borrower, b. phonenumber as 
                    borrower, c.name as     librarian, c.phonenumber as librarian
                from booklended.a, librarian.c, borrower.b
   where a. librarian id= c.librarianid
       and a.librarycard = b.librarycard
         and returndate < curdate()
         and cost  > 10.00
                order by a. returndate desc;
```

However I am getting this error
        5: invalid schema name: BOOKLENDED in statement [Select a.returndate as booklended ,a.isbn_number as booklended, b. as borrower, b.address as borrower, b.postalcode as borrower, b. phonenumber as borrower, c.name as librarian, c.phonenumber as librarian

from booklended.a]

Could I please get a guide on how I may correct this. Thank you

Comment: The error says "you have no database named booklended".

Comment: a, b and c are aliases for the tables. An alias is created either by writing 'booklended a' (no period) or 'booklended as a', depending on your database manager. It looks like your problem stems from the use of periods in the table names. The 'where' statement looks problematic as well.

Comment: Also, do not use implicit (comma-) join syntax. Use explicit JOIN syntax instead.

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
Select a.returndate as booklended ,a.isbn_number as isbnNumber, b.[YOUR COLUMNNAME FROM BORROWER TABLE] as borrower,        b.address as borrower, b.postalcode as borrower, b. phonenumber as borrower, c.name as     librarian, c.phonenumber as librarian

  from booklended as a, librarian as c, borrower as b
   where a.librarian id= c.librarianid
       and a.librarycard = b.librarycard
         and returndate < curdate()
         and cost  > 10.00
                order by a. returndate desc;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response however I got the following error.1: Column not found: B.AS in statement [Select a.returndate as booklended ,a.isbn_number as isbnNumber, b. as borrower,        b.address as borrower, b.postalcode as borrower, b. phonenumber as borrower, c.name as     librarian, c.phonenumber as librarian

  from booklended as a, librarian as c, borrower as b
   where a.librarian ]

Comment: for that add those columns to your table.thatsall

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Select a.returndate as booklended ,a.isbn_number as booklended,     
b.address as borrower, b.postalcode as borrower, b.phonenumber as 
borrower, c.name as librarian, c.phonenumber as librarian
from booklended a, librarian c, borrower b
where a. librarian id= c.librarianid
and a.librarycard = b.librarycard
and returndate < curdate()
and cost  > 10.00
order by a.returndate desc;
```